# HTTP Get request with non String values in Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters for Uri.http fails. Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-web

I'm sending a get request from Flutter web app to my Node server with query parameters using Uri as:

```
Uri.http(Environment.dbUrl, '/api/routes', queryParameters)
```

What I've experienced is that if I send all Strings as values in the queryParameters as:

```
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {

      'tlLat': minLat.toString(),
      'brLat': maxLat.toString(),
      'tlLong': minLong.toString(),
      'brLong': maxLong.toString(),
      'isPublic': 'true',
      'weekdays': weekdaysRange,
      'minTime': timeRange.first,
      'maxTime': timeRange.last
    };
```

the get request get sent while if I use type values as doubles and Boolean as:

```
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {

      'tlLat': minLat, //double
      'brLat': maxLat, //double
      'tlLong': minLong, //double
      'brLong': maxLong, //double
      'isPublic': true, // Boolean
      'weekdays': weekdaysRange, //[String]
      'minTime': timeRange.first, //[String]
      'maxTime': timeRange.last // [String]
    };
```

then the request doesn't get sent..so I've changed all types in my Node Schema and mongoose queries.
What am I doing wrong with the request ??

```
Future<List<UserRoute>> loadRoutesForRanges({
    @required String cityDb,
    @required String regionDb,
    @required String countryDb,
    @required double minLat,
    @required double maxLat,
    @required double minLong,
    @required double maxLong,
    @required List<String> timeRange,
    @required List<String> weekdaysRange
  }) async {
    print('MongoRepository.loadRoutesForRanges started');
    List<UserRoute> cityRoutes = [];

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'api_key': Environment.dbApiKey
    };


    Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {

      'tlLat': minLat.toString(),
      'brLat': maxLat.toString(),
      'tlLong': minLong.toString(),
      'brLong': maxLong.toString(),
      'isPublic': 'true',
      'weekdays': weekdaysRange,
      'minTime': timeRange.first,
      'maxTime': timeRange.last
    };

    print('RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutesForRanges query params are: $queryParameters'); // correct

    final Uri uri = UniversalPlatform.isWeb
        ? Uri.http(Environment.dbUrl, '/api/routes', queryParameters)
        : Uri.https(Environment.dbUrl, '/api/routes', queryParameters);

    print('RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutesForRanges uri is ${uri.toString()}'); // no prints when using type values in queryParameters

    await get(uri, headers: headers).then((resp) {
      print(
          'RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutesForRanges response status code is: ${resp.statusCode}, \n response is : ${jsonDecode(resp.body)}');
      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = jsonDecode(resp.body)['data'];
        // print('RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutes data is $data');
        data.forEach((element) {
          // print('RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutes route is $element');
          cityRoutes.add(UserRoute.fromMongo(element));
        });
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('RouteMongoRepository.loadRoutesForRanges error: $e');
    });
    return cityRoutes;
  }
```